# What is the fix for a swiftUI ios app with Firebase framework error to build and run on a connected device?

Tags: ios, firebase, debugging, swiftui

## ***What is the fix for a SwiftUI iOS app with Firebase framework error not allowing to build and run on connected devices?***

Xcode builds and runs the code flawless in the Canvas panel and Simulator, but does not build and run on connected devices.

(on a new project)

**Error Messages :**
[image]
[image]

Thread 1 #0 0x00000001029172ac in __abort_with_payload ()

```
dyld`__abort_with_payload:
0x1029172a4 <+0>:  mov    x16, #0x209
0x1029172a8 <+4>:  svc    #0x80
->  0x1029172ac <+8>:  b.lo   0x1029172c8               ; <+36>
0x1029172b0 <+12>: stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-0x10]!
0x1029172b4 <+16>: mov    x29, sp
0x1029172b8 <+20>: bl     0x1029157d8               ; cerror_nocancel
0x1029172bc <+24>: mov    sp, x29
0x1029172c0 <+28>: ldp    x29, x30, [sp], #0x10
0x1029172c4 <+32>: ret    
0x1029172c8 <+36>: ret'
```

debug area

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises
Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1ECE175B-46E5-4FC0-A28A- 
BC3255C9F124/Bennett Application.app/Bennett Application
Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1ECE175B-46E5-4FC0-A28A-BC3255C9F124/Bennett 
Application.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises: code signature invalid for 
'/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/1ECE175B-46E5-4FC0-A28A-BC3255C9F124/Bennett 
Application.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises'
```

Also, when you deploy an iOS app to the store, will you encounter similar problems as above?

Comment: Can you post your code here? Which version of iOS are you running on the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was simply fixed by upgrading to the Apple Developers Program.